# Java isEmpty() undefined for String?

Tags: java, eclipse, string

I'm working on a school project in eclipse, and when I try and use the `isEmpty()` method on a `String`, Eclipse shows up the following error:

> The method isEmpty() is undefined for the type String

I've run the Java updates, but am still getting it. Is any reason why this method would be undefined?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

String.isEmpty() was added in [Java 6](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty%28%29). In earlier versions you can use [`StringUtils.isEmpty(String)`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isEmpty%28java.lang.String%29) from [Apache's commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) library.

To configure Eclipse to use the 1.6 JRE, go to Window->Preferences->Java->Installed JREs. If you haven't already got JAva 1.6 configured, select **Add...**,browse to your 1.6 installation and add it.

[image: installed JREs screenshot]

[image: configure JREs screenshot]
<sub>(source: [lumidant.com](http://www.lumidant.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/01/eclipse_edit_jre.png))</sub>

Comment: As this is a beginner question, perhaps it should be explicitly mentioned that that the StringUtils class is from a 3rd-party open-source library, Apache Commons Lang (http://commons.apache.org/lang/)

Comment: hey Jonik, sorry, one more question. i've got 1.6 working, but am now getting this error: ZoneInfo: /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Home/lib/zi/ZoneInfoMappings (No such file or directory) Is there something else in Eclipse I need to change?

Comment: I'm no mac expert, but this post (http://forums.rotoworld.com/index.php?showtopic=141894&st=0&p=1361182&#entry1361182) suggests a solution

Answer (score 13):

If you're not on Java 6, String.length() == 0 will return the same result as String.isEmpty().

Answer (score 8):

`String.isEmpty()` was introduced in Java release 1.6. You might want to check what JDK version you're using for your project. (I don't know much about Eclipse myself, but it should be somewhere in the project settings.)

Comment: great, thanks! I've just had a look and I'm on 1.5, even though I ran the lastets OSX java update, which is supposed to update to Java SE 6 version 1.6.0_05.

Comment: Check if you can get 1.6 added in Ecplise's "Installed JREs" as illustrated in Rich Seller's answer :)

Comment: @Aaron you pretty much have to manually change the `CurrentJDK` sym-link (located in `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions`) to point at 1.6 instead of 1.5 if you want 1.6 as your default JDK.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in a big project where all previous set-up were with Java 8 (general and project level compiler settings). The solution was to move to the top The "JRE System Library[jre1.8.0]" in the "Order and Export" tab in Build Path of the affected project.