# JSoup 1.6.0 on Android throws Exception: String.isEmpty() NoSuchMethodExists

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I'm trying to use JSoup 1.6.0 with my Android application and it throws a NoSuchMethodExists exception.

[This other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483534/java-isempty-undefined-for-string) tells me that isEmpty() was not added to Java JRE until 1.6 -- I've checked my JRE in eclipse, and it is 1.6, however when I try to run my app on my emulator it throws the above exception. Is there a fix, or should I just import the Apache Commons Lang library?

Comment: Rather than importing a whole external lib for that, you could write your own static method that can do the check for you.  As for the error you are getting, that's pretty odd.

Comment: Why not write the method yourself?  I think it is a one-liner.  That way you do not need to bring in ACLang...

Comment: Btw: this method is being used in another external library: JSoup. That's where the exception is being thrown (if that is relevant).

Comment: Did you take a look at your environment variables to make sure they are correct?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`String.isEmpty()` isn't available until API level 9. Instead, you can use `TextUtils.isEmpty()`.

It looks like JSoup 1.6 introduced code that uses `String.isEmpty()` and therefore will require Android API level 9. I would suggest using an older release of JSoup for now if you are targeting Android API level 8 or lower (Froyo).

This is being treated as a bug in JSoup 1.6.0 and you can expect a fix soon. See https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/103 for status.

Comment: But, now I see in your comments that this is being called from an external library. You'll need to make that change to JSoup yourself.

Comment: Yep. Thanks for clearing that up though -- I've set my target for Level 8, so there ya go.

Comment: It seems a bit odd to me, though, since it looks like there are no other questions regarding the use of JSoup in Android and this particular exception -- others seem to have had success for a while now. And, JSoup claims that it is compatible with Android: http://jsoup.org/download

Comment: It looks like a brand new version of JSoup was released *last night* ... perhaps this introduced a new incompatibility with Android as I am experiencing.

Comment: Updated answer to reflect that.

Comment: Apologies; I missed that in my compatibility checks. I'll be fixing jsoup's JRE 1.5 support asap.

Comment: No need to apologize -- you called it beta so you're off the hook ;) I (and I'm sure many many others) appreciate your work on this project. Thanks for your quick responses (on here and Twitter). Look forward to the fixes.