# Error when parsing string of HTML with Jsoup

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I'm making an Android app and I'm using JRE 6 and the latest jSoup library. I'm trying to parse a string containing HTML using the following method:

```
public static String html2text(String html) {
    return Jsoup.parse(html).text();
}
```

I get the following exception:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError java.lang.string.isEmpty

How can I rectify this?

Comment: Or use JSoup 1.5.2. I think they released a bad build today. 1.6.0 is supposed to JDK 1.5 compliant.

Comment: @MJB Thank you, I downloaded the version you mentioned and it worked.

Comment: Yes, I just filed the bug - the author has responded and says he will fix soon. However 1.6.0 is considered "beta" quality anyway, so you  probably should stick with it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSoup 1.6.0 on Android throws Exception: String.isEmpty() NoSuchMethodExists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6335788/jsoup-1-6-0-on-android-throws-exception-string-isempty-nosuchmethodexists)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I made a mistake :

which version of android sdk do you use ?

The isEmpty method has been introduced in [version 9 of android](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty%28%29).

A solution could be an upgrade to release 9 and above or a work around :

```
String a;
System.out.println( a.equals("") ):
```

Comment: My minSDKVersion is set to 3, should it be higher then so? My android sdk is completely up to date.

Comment: yes, 9. Before that it won't run. Look at the link I provided, version number is included for every method of the android sdk, in the dark banner holding the name of the method, but at the right side.

Comment: 9 is android 2.3. Isn't that a bit high?

Comment: @Nicklas O, yes that is, so use the work around if you prefer. You can also check at the stats of your app on the market and see the share represented by android versions before 9. For me it would be 40 % of users, so I use the work around.