# "isEmpty() is undefined for the type String" in Eclipse 1.7 compiler?

Tags: java, eclipse, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java isEmpty() undefined for String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483534/java-isempty-undefined-for-string)

I copied my code from one java project to another and I get the error:

> The method isEmpty() is undefined for the type String

But the same `isEmpty()` works perfectly fine for checking string in the original program.

Instead I can use `str.length()==0`. But wondering what would be the reason for this?

[edit] **All of this are done in the same eclipse compiler version 1.7 in the same machine.** i.e. Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler, I find the " Compiler compliance level as 1.7". Including the original program where isEmpty worked and the new program where it is not working.

My another project which has isEmpty works fine. I created a new proj and copied a part of code which has isEmpty and I am getting this error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483534/java-isempty-undefined-for-string

Comment: String isEmpty(): since version 1.6

Comment: Regarding your edit: It's not the version of the compiler that matters most (although this **is** important), but the Java compiler compliance level that Eclipse is set at. Please see my answer and follow the menus I've listed to set this compliance correctly for 1.6 or 1.7.

Comment: Yeah sorry I misinterpreted and mentioned as compiler version. Following your link, i.e. Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler, I find the " Compiler compliance level as 1.7". As I have asked before, this compliance level is for all projects in eclipse right.? Because my another project which has isEmpty works fine. I created a new proj and copied a part of code which has isEmpty and I am getting this error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

isEmpty is a method from Java 1.6 and your problem is that you've got Eclipse's Java compiler compliance level set < 1.6. The solution is to go into Eclipse's preferences and set the compiler's compliance level to 1.6 or higher.

Menus:

Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler.

**Edit**
SyncMaster states in a comment:

> ...  I find the " Compiler compliance level as 1.7".
>   ... I created a new proj and copied a part of code which has isEmpty and I am getting this error

Solution: What I've described above is for the "master" compliance level, but each project can override this. To check the project's compliance level, right-click the project in Eclipse's package explorer, click `Properties`, then `Java Compiler`. Then you can decide whether or not to enable project-specific settings and just what those settings should be.

Comment: Yeah sorry I misinterpreted, and mentioned as compiler version. Following your link, i.e. Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler, I find the " Compiler compliance level as 1.7". As I have asked before, this compliance level is for all projects in eclipse right.? Because my another project which has isEmpty works fine. I created a new proj and copied a part of code which has isEmpty and I am getting this error.

Comment: @SyncMaster: See edit to my answer above.

Comment: thanks. that was the problem. It was 1.5 set for that project:)

Comment: @SyncMaster: you're welcome. Glad you've got things working!

Answer (score 2):

You must be using an older version of java. isEmpty came in Java 1.6.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty()

Answer (score 1):

String.isEmpty appeared in java 6, so you're probably compiling your program for an earlier version of java.

There's no problem in using `str.length() == 0` as that's exactly what one would do in earlier versions of java.